# Stock Options for a company bought out in cash and stock

Tags: stocks, options

I have 3 options in August for the $195 call strike. The company was just bought out for $230 dollars which was $125 cash and the rest in stock. What is my option worth since part of it is in the other company stock.

Answer (score 1):

There is no chance the deal will complete before option expiration. Humana stock will open Monday close to the $235 buyout price, and the options will reflect that value. $40 plus a bit of time value, but with just 2 weeks to expiration, not much.